# Complexity of turning a d-degree polynomial to 2-degree polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, nonlinear-optimization

For a very simple example,

$(1+x)^4=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$ is a 4 degree polynomial, and I want to change it to a 2-degree polynomial by add more variables, for this example, we can simply let $y=x^2$, then it turns out to be

$y^2+4xy+6y+4x+1$

My question is for a general polynomial $(1+x_1+...+x_n)^d$, how many variables should we use to turn its expansion into a 2-degree polynomial? Any idea or reference suggested? I have no idea after thinking it for a while

To be more specific, given a unconstrained polynomial optimization problem,

$\min\ (1+x_1+...+x_n)^d$

how many additional variables do we need to turn it to a quadratic optimization problem with quadratic constraints, that is for something like

$\min \ x^8$

we can do the following

$\min \ y_1^2$

$s.t.y_1=y_2^2,y_2=x^2$

to represent, so here we need 2 more variables.

Comment: Your question is not well defined. As it is, one can just set $z:=p(x)-x^2$ to get $p(x)=x^2+z$, which has degree 2.

Comment: Presumably you want to minimize the (sum/max/product of the) degree(s) of the defining equation(s)?

Comment: I edited my question to state it more clearly now. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Also, your "general polynomial" has a very special form. For that polynomial, you can get rid of the exponent $d$ in the minimum problem, for instance.

Comment: In the example, it does has a special form, but I want to analyze a worst case which contains all the monomials, so analyzing $(1+x^1+...+x^n)^d$ will give an upper bound of the number of variables needed.

Comment: What's the restriction on "variables"? For a polynomial $p(x)$ let $y:=p$. Then the reduced polynomial is $y$, of degree $1$; or for $p:=q^n$, where q is of degree $1$, let $y:=q^{n-1}$. Then $p=q\cdot y$ has degree 2. Should "variables" be of degree 2?

Comment: My goal is to analyze the complexity of turning a general unconstrained polynomial minimization problem into a QP-with quadratic objectives (or linear) and quadratic constraints. After the transformation, the degree of all variables in obj and constraints should be less that or equal to 2. So like the case you mentioned, if we want to minimize $p=x^8$, we shouldn't use $y=x^7$, then $p=y x$, because after this, $y=x^7$ is a constraint and the degree of $x$ is still 7 in the constraints.

Comment: You are asking for a function of $n$ and $d$. Can you solve a special case where you fix one of those to be some small number and let the other vary?